# Bash coding in script programming

Tags: linux, bash

I am having problem with this program
it keeps on saying command not found
Could anyone help me out
1. Will display a menu as shown below –

Choose one of the followings –

1. Show My Student ID and Name
2. Find the divisors of an integer number
3. Exit
4. Based on the option chosen the script should do the following:

a. If option 1 is chosen, the script should echo your student id and name.

b. If option 2 is chosen, the script should ask for an integer number from the user
and then it should find divisor of that number.

c. If option 3 is chosen, the script should exit the program and return to
the terminal.

here is my script

```
echo "option 1.name and studentid"
echo "option 2.integer"
read osch
if [osch -eq 1]; then
echo "Nene MIT173520"
else
if [osch -eq 2}; then
read a
i=2
while i le a
do (a/i eq 0);
echo "i"
i=i+1
else exit
fi
```

Comment: If you are having problems with some code, please post that code as part of your question. Without seeing the code there's not much we can do to help.

Comment: will you please paste ur script..

Comment: I have added my codes

Comment: There are a number of basic syntax errors here; [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) will spot some of them. Among others: you need spaces between the elements of a test (i.e. after `[` and before `]`), you need to use `$` to get the value of a variable, the second `if` should be `elif` and you used a close squiggle bracket instead of square bracket, the `while` test express is missing almost everything (should be `[ "$i$ -le "$a" ]`), the thing after `do` should probably be `if` and a valid arithmetic test expression, ...

Comment: @GordonDavisson - just a shame I can't upvote a comment more than once...

Comment: A question should be about a single, specific problem, with only the shortest code needed to let someone reproduce that problem shown.

Comment: Add a shebang and then paste your script there: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 1):

What is the name of your script? And are you calling the script? If the script is not in your PATH, be sure to provide a relative path when calling the script. otherwise, update your PATH variable with the path to the script. I've just tested the script now and it runs except for syntax errors. so, please pay attention to how you are calling your script and it should work.

Comment: In [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), note the section "Answer Well-Asked Questions", and the bullet point therein regarding questions which "are unclear or lacking specific details that can uniquely identify the problem". If the advice that comes to mind is general as opposed to specific, that typically means that a question needs to be narrowed before it's on-topic (and thus answerable) here.

Comment: (Moreover, there are a lot of bugs in the OP's script that *aren't* addressed in this answer -- see Gordon Davisson's comment, keeping in mind that an ideal answer is canonical enough that it can be reasonably expected to address the question *in full*. That's not really feasible here, because said question isn't focused on a single narrow problem... but, well, that's part of why the prior link advises against trying to answer questions that aren't narrowly scoped).